# Problem when a component is replaced based on a state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, preact

I'm a beginner to React/Preact and I'm facing to a problem that I don't understand.
I have radio inputs to choose a component (FormInput) to display according to a state:

```
{
this.state.radio === true ?
    <FormInput id="keyword" name="keyword" required={true}>Keyword</FormInput> :
    <FormInput id="url" name="url" required={true} placeholder="https://" pattern={'https://.*'} >URL</FormInput>
}
```

`keyword` is displayed first, then I display `url` and a switch back to `keyword`. The render of the HTML is correct but when I switch back to the `keyword` input, the props of this input is the props of the `url` input.

But if I change the html rendering by adding `<></>` for example, I don't have the problem:

```
{
this.state.radio === true ?
    <><FormInput id="keyword" name="keyword" required={true}>Keyword</FormInput></> :
    <FormInput id="url" name="url" required={true} placeholder="https://" pattern={'https://.*'} >URL</FormInput>
}
```

What am I doing wrong please ?
Thank you.

Edit: FormInput code:

```
export function FormInput(props: InputProps) {
    const {
        id,
        name,
        value = '',
        required = false,
        disabled = false,
        readonly = false,
        type = 'text',
        autocomplete = 'off',
        pattern,
        children,
        placeholder = children,
        title = '',
        setRef,
        handleValueChange = () => {}
    } = props;
    let {classInputName = '', classGroupName = ''} = props;

    classInputName = classNames('form-control', classInputName)
    classGroupName = classNames('form-group', classGroupName)

    let inputDom = setRef;
    if(!setRef){
        inputDom = useRef(null) as Ref<HTMLInputElement>;
    }

    const onInput = useCallback((e: any) => {
        handleValueChange(name, e.target.value,);
    }, []);
    
    return (
        <div class={classGroupName}>
            {children ?
                <label for={id}>{children}{required ? <span title="Required" rel="tooltip" class="required badge badge-empty rounded-circle ml-2"/> : ''}</label>
                : <></>}
            <input
                ref={inputDom}
                {...{id, name, type, required, disabled, readonly, pattern, onInput, placeholder, value, autocomplete, title}}
                class={classInputName}
            />
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: If you're only displaying one radio button at a time why are you using radio buttons? They generally work in sets.

Comment: The radios are for the choice of the FormInput that are just inputs, with the radios I switch between `id="keyword"` or `id="url"`

Comment: Please add `FormInput` code.

Comment: I have edited the code with FormInput

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you switch `FormInput` component, React will try to re-use the old one for performance, so it will keep the old one's props, when you use `<></>` to wrap the keyword `FormInput`, react knows the sibling components are different, so it won't re-use your old component, you can try to add different `key` prop to `FormInput` component, like this to tell react they are different:

```
{
this.state.radio === true ?
    <FormInput key="keyword" id="keyword" name="keyword" required={true}>Keyword</FormInput> :
    <FormInput key="url" id="url" name="url" required={true} placeholder="https://" pattern={'https://.*'} >URL</FormInput>
}
```

Further information: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#gatsby-focus-wrapper

Comment: Thank you for your help !